Insulation on an old 1800's era house
I’ve started to reno our kitchen to our 1865 home in Ontario. We pulled the paneling off the wall and found pink insulation but when I pulled it away from the studding I noticed that there was a large cavity in behind that was not insulated. They built a 2x4 wall about 2-3 inches away from the exterior of the house and then but batts of insulation within the 2x4. I was thinking of ripping 4” strips of plywood and putting them on the 2x4 then spray foaming the gaps to minimize the air flow then put in r20 insulation for 2x6 walls. Would this work? Or should I do another approach? Thanks!

Can you draw a cross section of the wall? Is it just this wall or do you want to do the whole house? You can use https://www.ubakus.de/en/r-value-calculator/ to build a model of the wall and simulate it. It will tell you if you have dew point and condensation issue in the insulation.

BTW, what is the climate in you locale? Insulation recommendation varies with need for heating and cooling.

I’m located in Southern Ontario Canada.

that's only a 160 year old house

@Dpell please add the location information to your question ... a comment is not a suitable place for it

I take it you do plan to remove the inner surfaces of the walls to do this. If you wanted to avoid that, I've consider blown-in insulation, reducing the repair afterward to closing the access holes.

Side comment: if this is balloon construction, you may want to consider taking advantage of the opportunity to install fire blocks, to keep wall cavities from becoming chimneys in case of fire. Though filling them with sufficient insulation also reduces that risk.
